# how to store all mobile data in computer without touch mobile screen?? H

Tags: backup, broken-screen

How to get my all data(Like contacts,messages,files,etc) when my mobile screen was broken.

I am used Galaxy j7.And I loss my mobile display by some reason.

My phone still working,but i see all things on screen but dont touch on scrren

call was incoming.

But when I connect my phone with my pc via samsung component .then

Please help me

How can I get all my data.

Comment: Please suggest me....it's needful

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways for you to fetch the data. 
A very easy way for you to control the screen is to **use a mouse**.
If you are familiar with **Android Debug Bridge (ADB)**, you can use it as well.

Comment: i dont know about ADB, so can you please tell me something about it?

Comment: But sir, for what you say, I have to touch the screen ... And, my mobile touch is damaged.so how to do this.

Comment: @priyapatil If you are not familiar with ADB, I suggest you to buy an OTG adapter and a mouse. Connect the mouse to your phone using the adapter and you are good to go.